# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Python 3.3

Tags: python, function

In this program I have the user enter an equation and display it back to them.

The problem I'm having is that when I call the function that asks for the equation again I get a TypeError. I have know why I keep getting this error and have tried multiple ways to try and fix it. help?

```
import parser
def eq():   
    global eq
    global eq_parsed
    while True:
        eq = input('f(x) = ')
        try:
            eq_parsed = parser.expr(eq).compile()
            x=0
            eval(eq_parsed)
            break
        except:
            print("invalid equation")
    print ("Your equation: f(x)=", eq)
    mark=True
    return (mark)
T=True
mark=False
while T==True:
    if mark==False:
        n=input("\nStart? (y/n): ")
    elif mark==True:
        n=input("\nStart Again? (y/n): ")
#----------------------------------------
    if n=='y':
        mark = eq()
    elif n=='n':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Input*")
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest against the use of global variables. If a function needs to use them you should be passing them in as parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `eq` to be both the function name and a global variable. So when you write `eq()`, the name `eq` refers to the global variable.

```
def eq(): # eq refers to this function
    global eq 
    ....
    eq = input('f(x) = ') # now eq refers to the string object return by input
....
mark = eq() # and a string object is not callable
```

You'll make your life a lot easier if you use a different name for the function and the global string variable. And the other way to make things a lot cleaner is to stop using `global`, and return anything that the caller needs in the return statement of the function.

```
def eq():   
    while True:
        eq_input = input('f(x) = ')
        try:
            eq_parsed = parser.expr(eq).compile()
            x=0
            eval(eq_parsed)
            break
        except:
            print("invalid equation")
    print ("Your equation: f(x)=", eq_input)
    return True, eq_input, eq_parsed
```

And then call it like this:

```
mark, eq_input, eq_parsed = eq()
```

Not that you currently appear to use the values assigned to `eq_input` and `eq_parsed` outside the function. In which case, you don't need to return them at all and they can remain local to the function.

It is idiomatic to write

```
if val:
```

rather than

```
if val == True:
```

And similarly

```
if not val:
```

is preferred over

```
if val == False:
```

Answer (score 2):

You have named your function `eq()`, and you also have a global variable named `eq`. You can't have both. Since Python (generally) evaluates from the top down, first the function's name is assigned to the identifier `eq`, then later on the results of the `input()` call are. When you try to call `eq()` down at the bottom, you get the error, as Python thinks you're trying to call a string.

Perhaps name the variable `equation`, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
def eq():   
     global eq
     # ...
     eq = input('f(x) = ')
```

globally redefines `eq` to the content of input when `eq` is called, which is a string. use different names for your functions and variables.

Therefore, you can call `eq` exactly once, and then it refers to a string and no longer to a function.